# Java - Reflection setting value at runtime

Tags: java, reflection, access-modifiers

i try to set values for the field available in a java bean like the following and i want to omit the static final fields:

```
public Class creatObjectWithDefaultValue(String className) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        DefaultParamValues defaultParamValues = null;
        Class objectClass = null;
        try {
            objectClass = Class.forName(className);
             Field[] fields = objectClass.getDeclaredFields();

             for(Field f:fields){
                 f.setAccessible(true);
                    //if(!f.isAccessible()){
                       // f.setAccessible(true);
                        Class<?> type = f.getType();


                        if(! Modifier.isFinal(f.getModifiers()) && type.equals(Integer.class)){
                            f.set(objectClass, defaultParamValues.INTEGER);  
                        } else if(! Modifier.isFinal(f.getModifiers()) && type.equals(BigInteger.class)){
                            f.set(objectClass, defaultParamValues.BIGINTEGER);  
                        }/*else if(! Modifier.isFinal(f.getModifiers()) && type.equals(LocalDate.class)){
                            f.set(objectClass, defaultParamValues.DATE);  
                        }*/else if(! Modifier.isFinal(f.getModifiers()) && type.equals(Boolean.class)){
                            f.set(objectClass, defaultParamValues.BOOLEAN);  
                        }else if(! Modifier.isFinal(f.getModifiers()) && type.equals(Long.class)){
                            f.set(objectClass, defaultParamValues.LONGVALUE);  
                        }
                        f.setAccessible(false);
                    //}
                        //To print the value set
                        if(! Modifier.isFinal(f.getModifiers()) ){
                             System.out.println(f.get(objectClass));
                        }

                }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return objectClass;
    }
```

i get the following exception when i run the program : the complete stack strace is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.hexgen.tools.JsonConverter can not access a member of class com.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO with modifiers "private"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:65)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.doSecurityCheck(Field.java:960)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:896)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:358)
    at com.hexgen.tools.JsonConverter.creatObjectWithDefaultValue(JsonConverter.java:89)
    at com.hexgen.tools.JsonConverter.main(JsonConverter.java:181)
```

what is the problem ? Could somebody help me to fix this?

Best Regards.

Comment: JsonConverter.java:89 <-- which line is this?

Comment: f.setAccessible(false);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You revert the `accessible` property of the field to `false` and then you go on to access its value.

Don't bother with setting accessible back to false.

Comment: Thanks Marko, still i get this `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.hexgen.tools.JsonConverter can not access a member of class com.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO with modifiers "private"`

Comment: I think that this isn't the problem here. Check my answer.

Comment: Listen to Adam's advice, he's got it right. You aren't creating an instance of the class, so your current code only works for `static` fields.

Comment: @AdamArold It is not true that this *isn't* the problem: it just isn't *the only* problem.

Comment: I see, you are right. We are facing multiple problems here. But hey, it is reflection...

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is that you are trying to set fields on a class not an instance of that class.

First you should create an instance of your `objectClass` and set the values of the instance!

Here:

```
f.set(objectClass, defaultParamValues.INTEGER);
```

you are passing the class object, not an instance of that class.
The problem occurs when your program encounters a field which is not `static`, hence your `Exception`.

If you want to filter for `static` fields you can use:

```
java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())
```

Comment: i created new instance like the following but still i get the same `objectClass.newInstance();`

Comment: Can you update your code please? With something indicating on which line you get the Exception.

Comment: ` if(! Modifier.isFinal(f.getModifiers()) ){
                    System.out.println(f.get(objectClass));
                  }` is the place where i get exception

Comment: The same exception as before?

Comment: Can you launch your debugger and figure it out that on which method call does it throw the exception?